# How can I replace the javascript timeout with the AngularJS timeout?

Tags: angularjs

When I open a modal if the variable `home.autoSave` is true I would like to execute the following function `home.modalSubmit()` every 60 seconds after the opening. When I close the modal I need this to stop.

Is this something I can do with AngularJS or do I need to use the timeout from Javascript? I saw this code but I wonder if there is an easier way to do this with AngularJS:

```
home.modalOpen = function () {
    var autoSubmit = function () {
        if ((home.view === "edit" || home.view === "new") && !home.forms.modal.$pristine) {
            home.modalSubmit(true);
        }
    };
    if (home.autoSave) {
        home.modal.timeout = window.setTimeout(function () {
            home.modal.interval = window.setInterval(function () {
                autoSubmit();
            }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
            autoSubmit();
        }, 2 * 60 * 1000);
    }
```

Also is there a way I could keep the autoSubmit function code inside a function block as it is only used in these two places.

Comment: Angular have `$timeout` and `$interval` services. Their syntax is exactly like `setTimeout`. I don't understand your second question. What do you mean by "keep the autoSubmit function code inside a function block"?

Comment: The function is just used twice so I was wondering if I could somehow just define it as anonymous and use it inline

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: [_How to Auto-Save your model in Angular.js using $watch and a Debounce function_](http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/10/30/auto-save-your-model-in-angular-js-with-watch-and-debounce/). The post includes an example of using `$timeout`, but the approach is a little different from yours.